# PyTorch Transformer Model, some values are always 0

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer-model

As a bit of background I've implemented a slightly customized transformer model in PyTorch.

However, I'm consistently getting 0's in certain indices of my output :

[image: Tensor with 0's in certain positions]

The target data is dense and has no zero values. Strangely, the loss is quite low as the non-zero values predicted are quite close to their target equivalents. Moreover, it's always the exact same indices that are set to 0:

[image: Batch Tensor with 0's in same position]

This makes little sense to me as the model seems to work perfectly fine with another dataset (an english-french dataset where words are tokenized and passed into an embedding layer). My data is all between 0 and 1 so I doubt there is any clipping happening, and I am using ReLU as my activation function at the final layer of my model. While I have dropout layers in my model, the dropout value has already been set to 0.

My final layer:

```
y = F.relu(self.linear4(y))
```

I originally thought it could've been the masking required for the attention mechanism, but I have this implemented within the attention mechanism right before the softmax portion of scaled dot-product attention. This means it shouldn't really have an effect on the output; moreover, the add & normalize steps should propagate a gradient through no matter what. To confirm this I have tried removing the mask and seen that it does not affect the 0's in my output.

I'm wondering what could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Well 0 values here aren't unexpected right ? Also relu converts any neg values to 0. So even it those indexes had different negative values learnt, they are being converted to 0.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists even after removing activation. It's a bit random though